# == vs. equals() references/pointers JAVA

Tags: java, pointers, reference

I'm learning about == vs. equals() and doing various examples. For this one, I understand why r==s is false, but why is r.equals(s) false if they now both have the same content?

```
public class StringProgram{
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Person r = new Person("A");
    Person s = new Person("J");
    s.setName("A");

    System.out.println(r.getName());//A
    System.out.println(s.getName());//A
    System.out.println(r==s);//false
    System.out.println(r.equals(s));//false


  }
}
```

Here is the code of `Person` :

```
public class Person{
    private String name;

    public Person(String d){
    name=d;
    }
    public void setName(String a){
      name=a;
    }

    public String getName(){
      return name;
    }
}
```

EDIT: I see that I have to override it now, but I still don't understand how the assignment works in the example below. I just don't understand why t.getName() is Keen if t is assigned to u.

public class StringProgram{
  public static void main(String[] args) {

```
Person t = new Person("Gene");
Person u = t;
u.setName("Keen");

System.out.println(t.getName());//Keen
System.out.println(t.equals(u));//true
```

}
}

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java == vs equals() confusion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520432/java-vs-equals-confusion)

Comment: How could we know without the code of `Person` ?

Comment: @pathfinderelite you can't say it's a duplicate before the question has been clarified

Comment: public class Person{
    private String name;
    
    public Person(String d){
    name=d;
    }
    public void setName(String a){
      name=a;
    }
    
    public String getName(){
      return name;
    }

Comment: You need to override [`equals`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) in `Person`.

Comment: The deal with the u and t question is that u and t are both references, and when u is assigned to t (`u = t`) they both refer to the same object. So changing the state of u's object changes the object t points to as well.

Answer (score 0):

`equals()` is just a method, there's nothing special about it. In particular, it doesn't automatically know how to compare the content of two objects.

The `equals()` method of class `Object` does the same thing as `==`. If you do not override the `equals()` method in your class `Person`, then it's not automatically going to compare the content of `Person` objects.

You have to override the `equals()` method in class `Person` so that it does the comparison in the way you want.

```
public class Person {
    private String name;

    // ...

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (!(o instanceof Person)) {
            return false;
        }

        return ((Person) o).name.equals(this.name);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! However, I'm not exactly sure how to override the method, do you have resources on how to do it?

Comment: Quite a weak implementation of  `equals`. It will explode at anytime.

Answer (score 0):

All classes in java inherit from the [Object](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html) class. When you do an `r.equals(s)`, it uses the .equals() method as defined in Object class. To make it work as you desire, you need to define the .equals() method for the Person class by overriding the .equals() method.

Eg. Add this in your Person class:

```
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Person other = (Person) obj;
        if (name == null) {
            if (other.name != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!name.equals(other.name))
            return false;
        return true;
    }
```

Note: I used eclipse to generate the equals and hashcode method for me. You may read [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265503/why-do-i-need-to-override-the-equals-and-hashcode-methods-in-java) to understand why hashcode() needs to be overridden.

Answer (score 0):

Java can't guess what you want to do, you have to tell it that two persons are the same if they have the same name. You must override `equals` :

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
   if (o == this) return true;
   if (o == null) return false;
   if (!(o instanceof Person)) return false;
   Person that = (Person) o;

   if (name == null && that.name == null) return true;
   if (name == null || that.name == null) return false;
   return that.name.equals(name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All java classes inherits from Object, and to properly compare your class you should override the `equals()` method.

```
public Person(String d){
name=d;
}
public void setName(String a){
  name=a;
}

public String getName(){
  return name;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
  return obj instanceof Person && 
         this.getName().equals(((Person)obj).getName());
}
```